# Rows is not Iterable Error in EJS response

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, node-sqlite3

Hello I am getting an error in my EJS response file I am trying to display my form data that makes a request to my   database on the server side and I am getting this error here is the Form Code and the Server side

```
<body>
   
    <form  method="POST" action="/user/post">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" ></td>
        </tr>
      
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save" ></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>   
   
</body>
```

```
<html>
  <head>
    
    <title>Message Logs</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
        <% for (var row of rows) { %>
            <div><%= row.username %> <%= row.message %></div>    
          <% } %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
app.post('/user/post',function(req,res){
  db.all(`SELECT * FROM messages WHERE name='${req.body.username}'`, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    
    res.render('userinfo', { rows: rows });
  });
```

I am expecting it to display my database query it is an sqlite3 database and the table name is : messages with the fields : username , message

Answer (score 0):

Found the error just a syntax mistake in the db query should have been WHERE username not where name